# One of my answers keeps getting spammed

Tags: support, spam

For some reason this answer

https://serverfault.com/a/671363/1435

keeps getting editing by spammers, can we just lock the question for good?

Comment: Consider it [done](https://serverfault.com/a/671363/37681).

Comment: @HBruijn The request was to lock the entire question, though; any reason to only lock this one answer?

Comment: @tripleee It's only the answer that's being said to receive spam edits; locking the whole question would be overkill. (It'd be another matter if *every* post was receiving spam edits, but that's not what's being asserted.)

Comment: Sure, just hoping to ascertain that the discrepancy is not an oversight.

Comment: @tripleee The question is already protected and unless  I misread the request and the (for non-moderators not visible) review histories it is as Chopper3 ascertained - only that particular answer  seems problematic with regards to spam edits that keep getting rejected from the review queues. What I did is smallest application of moderator powers

Comment: I don't mind/care what you do, just feel slightly guilty that it's my answer that's causing so much admin for you is all.

Comment: @HBruijn I was the one who protected the question in an attempt to address the spam edits. However that turned out to not be sufficient, so two weeks ago I flagged the question for moderator attention and got this answer: **I can't see a "disallow anon edits" button, so I've locked for a week to hopefully discourage the stupidity. Sadly all edits are from different IPs, no help there.**

Comment: @kasperd I hope this is the cure

Comment: @HBruijn I don't see anything different from before. I suppose we'll see if the spam edits keep coming.

Comment: @kasperd Locks (on answers) come with a default expiry of 1 hour, to make them permanent your friendly moderator needs to pay attention and select the correct option in the pulldown menu....

Comment: @HBruijn We could maybe lock the question with the 'Historical lock' as I think that it would lock the questions and answer completely ? forever. (The downside is that it would prevent upvote)

Comment: @HBruijn The problem persists: https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/371044

Answer (score 6):

After applying minimal mod-hammer and locking only your answer, I had to lock the whole question since the spam edits started on another answer.